# How to take XML data from API and extract data list from it

Tags: xml, flutter, dart

I am calling an API that returns `XML` data

I have a Class for the data to take the part of the data that I need.

The API returns the `instances` fine but I am having trouble extracting the data List I need to then call a function (Which is tested and works) to place a `map marker`.

I need to take the `lat, long` from the returned list `vehicleactivity` and use it

This is the Class

```
import 'package:xml/xml.dart';

class VehicleActivity {
  VehicleActivity({
    this.recordedAtTime,
    this.itemIdentifier,
    this.validUntilTime,
    this.longitude,
    this.latitude,
  });

  DateTime? recordedAtTime;
  String? itemIdentifier;
  DateTime? validUntilTime;
  double? longitude;
  double? latitude;

  factory VehicleActivity.fromElement(XmlElement vaElement) => VehicleActivity(
        recordedAtTime: DateTime.parse(
          vaElement.findElements('RecordedAtTime').first.text,
        ),
        itemIdentifier: vaElement.findElements('ItemIdentifier').first.text,
        validUntilTime: DateTime.parse(
          vaElement.findElements('ValidUntilTime').first.text,
        ),
        longitude: 
            double.tryParse(vaElement.findAllElements('Longitude').first.text),

        latitude:
            double.tryParse(vaElement.findAllElements('Latitude').first.text),
      );
}
```

I am calling it with this API fetch

```
   Future <VehicleActivity?> fetchLiveLocations() async {
    var client = http.Client();
    VehicleActivity? vehicleActivity;
    

    
  try{
    var response = await client.get(Uri.parse(
      'https_call'));   
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {

  final doc = XmlDocument.parse(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
  final vehicleActivity = doc
      .findAllElements('VehicleActivity')
      .map((e) => VehicleActivity.fromElement(e))
      .toList();
  print(vehicleActivity);

  }
 } catch(e) {

  print("Exception Happened: ${e.toString()}");
}
return vehicleActivity; 
}
```

To then plot the marker I use this function, this is where the issue is.

```
Future<void> showMapMarkers() async {
    _unTiltMap();

    var vehicleActivity = await fetchLiveLocations();
  for (VehicleActivity vehicleActivity in vehicleActivity!) {
    GeoCoordinates geoCoordinates = GeoCoordinates (vehicleActivity.latitude, vehicleActivity.latitude);
    

    _addMapMarker(geoCoordinates, 1);
  
  }
}
```

This is the issue

```
     The type 'VehicleActivity' used in the 'for' loop must implement Iterable.
```

On this line

```
    for (VehicleActivity vehicleActivity in vehicleActivity!) {
```

update - Function to plot not recognising (I use a `for` method for my Json, this could be the issue but have tried other options)

```
        Future<void> showMapMarkers() async {
    _unTiltMap();

    var vehicleActivity = await fetchLiveLocations();
  for (VehicleActivity vehicleActivity in vehicleActivity!) {
    GeoCoordinates geoCoordinates = GeoCoordinates (vehicleActivity.latitude, vehicleActivity.latitude);
    

    _addMapMarker(geoCoordinates, 1);
  
  }
}
```

Comment: final vehicleActivity = doc
      .findAllElements('VehicleActivity')
      .map((e) => VehicleActivity.fromElement(e))
      .toList();
  print(vehicleActivity);. // share the output of this print

Comment: Have updated question. I need to get ```lat,long``` from the list ```vehicleactivity``` and place markers. Marker placement function works, its just extracting the lat,long

Comment: Change `Future <VehicleActivity?> fetchLiveLocations() async` to `Future List<<VehicleActivity>> fetchLiveLocations() async`

Comment: And you should decide when to do if there's an exception. Do you really want to return `null` as now, or throw the exception, or return `<VehicleActivity>[]` (i.e. an empty list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle the issues in the comments:

1. It should actually be returning a list (note the `toList()`)
2. It should return something (not null - at least for now) on exception or non-200

Rewrite this method as:

```
Future<List<VehicleActivity>> fetchLiveLocations() async {
  var client = http.Client();

  try {
    var response = await client.get(Uri.parse('https_call'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final doc = XmlDocument.parse(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
      return doc
          .findAllElements('VehicleActivity')
          .map((e) => VehicleActivity.fromElement(e))
          .toList();
    } else {
      // todo - fix later - for now return empty list
      return <VehicleActivity>[];
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print('Exception Happened: ${e.toString()}');
    // todo - fix later - for now return empty list
    return <VehicleActivity>[];
  }
}
```

Comment: Function to plot the marker (Have highlighted in update) is now not recognising the vehicleActivity class throwing this error ```The argument type 'double?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'double'.``` I must need to access each lat,long from the XML call and then use my method to plot

Comment: `longitude` is a `double?` so could be null. When you reference it, either use a `!` or a null-aware operator, like `myVehicleActivity.longitude ?? 0.0`

Comment: Only way to make it accept was to use a ```Null Coalescing Operator (??)```. Main file has no errors but the Class won't accept it. Is this the right direction to be heading in? If so I'll figure it out

Comment: Do I need to extract Lat, Long as part of the API call?

Comment: i've no idea what that last question means

Comment: Should I use the ```.findAllElements``` line to pull the lat/long, so that it produces a list there and then, enabling me to pull the result

Comment: Have managed to get it working, thank you for your help